# Transforming jquery function into functional programming function

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm a beginner in functional programming and 
I want to transform this jquery function with the functional programming paradigm.

I try to transform this function

```
merge: function( first, second ) {
            var len = +second.length,
                j = 0,
                i = first.length;

            for ( ; j < len; j++ ) {
                first[ i++ ] = second[ j ];
            }

            first.length = i;

            return first;
        }
```

It is just a simple merge function.
For example, when I call

```
merge([0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9]);
```

It produces

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

What I did is

```
merge: function( first, second ){
    var len = +second.length,
                j = 0,
                i = first.length;
    let modify = x =>{
    let merging =
        j => {
        first[ i++ ] = second[ j ];
        };
    R.map(merging, R.range(0,len))
    return first;
    }
    modify
}
```

But it does not work.
I know something is wrong in my code but I cannot guess where is it...

Comment: btw, you have a plain javascript function. no jquery.

Comment: Oh, I modified it

Comment: What is this R?

Comment: I declared before like const R = require('ramda')

Comment: Note that although `merge` means something else in Ramda, this function is already available in Ramda, as `concat`.

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming forbids mutation (for example, any `obj[prop] =` assignment is mutation). If you want to make this functional (and easy), just `concat` the first array with the second:

```js
console.log(merge([0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9]));

function merge(first, second){
  return first.concat(second);
}
```

Comment: What if         let merge = first=>
                       {
   return R.concat(first, second);
}

Comment: That wouldn't be a pure function - `second` should be an argument. But if you want to use `R.concat`, that's fine

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) them with ES6 into a new one:

```js
console.log([...[0,1,2,3,4], ...[5,6,7,8,9]])

// OR if you really want a pure function

let mergeArrays = (a,b) => [...a, ...b]

console.log(mergeArrays([0,1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9]))
```