# Jquery test suite does not pass

Tags: javascript, jquery, ramda.js

I'm the beginner in the jquery and functional programming
I transformed the jquery function into the functional programming paradigm and the following one is the original jquery function

```
   merge: function( first, second ) {
            var len = +second.length,
                j = 0,
                i = first.length;

            for ( ; j < len; j++ ) {
                first[ i++ ] = second[ j ];
            }

            first.length = i;

            return first;
        },
```

And I transformed that like

```
 merge: function( first, second ) {
            var len = +second.length,
                j = 0,
                i = first.length;

            let main = (first,second)=>
            {return R.concat(first, second);}
            first.length = i;

        return main(first,second)
        },
```

But Jquery test suite does not pass.
It just passes up to test number 5
(ready: Error in ready callback does not halt all future executions (gh-1823) (1))
and does not pass from test 6.
I think my code has some side effects. But I cannot guess. 
Is there anyone who can find it?

Answer (score 0):

While [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56197421/1243641) to your other question shows how you can write this function more simply, and while we don't have enough information to know why your test suite is failing (next time include the test that is failing), we can look at your function.  Slightly reformatted, this is

```
const merge = function( first, second ) {
    var len = +second.length,
        j = 0,
        i = first.length;

    let main = (first,second) => {
        return R.concat(first, second);
    }
    first.length = i;

    return main(first,second)
}
```

Now let's simplify that.  Your return statement is `return main(first, second)`.  And that `main` function does not depend at all upon `len`, `j`, or `i`, and resetting `first.length` to the value that was just set from `first.length` does nothing.  So this can be just as easily written as

```js
const merge = function( first, second ) {
    let main = (first,second) => {
        return R.concat(first, second);
    }

    return main(first,second)
}
```

But now note that your helper function, has nothing in its closure except for the parameters to the outer function, and those are shadowed by its own parameters.  Which means that you can eliminate it entirely, and just use its body.

So we get to

```js
const merge = function( first, second ) {
    return R.concat(first, second);
}
```

And finally, functions of the format `function(p1, p2, ..., pn) {return anotherFunc(p1, p2, ..., pn);}` aren't doing anything more than renaming `anotherFunc`..

So in the end, you can just write

```js
const merge = R.concat
```

I don't know why your function had that additional work, but it was all unnecessary.  I can't see how any of it would cause the test suite to fail, as you did write a function that should still work, and there are no obvious side-effects, but perhaps the test system actually tracked the change to the length of its parameters.  That would be unusual, but certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything from your code what might cause that error. The code relating to [that test case](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/test/unit/ready.js#L138-L150) in jQuery should be completely unrelated.

That said, one of the differences between the two functions is that the jQuery `merge` inserts the elements of `second` onto the end of the `first` array instance. `R.concat` however treats the arguments as immutable, returning a new array containing all the elements of `first` and `second` leaving the original `first` and `second` arrays unmodified. n.b. This will produce differences in behaviour if the in-place modification of the array in the jQuery function is relied upon.

On a side note, your second example can also be simplified like so:

```
merge: function( first, second ) {
  return R.concat(first, second);
}
```

Or more simply:

```
merge: R.concat
```